# Dynamic loading jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Currently I have 02 jar files, a.jar and b.jar, both of the jar files contains a class name MyClass, which is in the same package name "application.test", which have a same method

```
void run (){ ...}
```

In a.jar, the run method is implemented as following

```
void run (){
     System.out.print("a.jar");
}
```

In b.jar, the run method is implemented as following

```
void run (){
     System.out.print("b.jar");
}
```

In my main application, I will dynamically loads exists jar files in its lib folder by doing as below:

```
public class DynamicLoader{
    public Class<?> classToLoad;
    public Object instance;
    public String classname;

    public DynamicLoader(URL[] JarURL, String classname) {
        URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(JarURL, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        this.classname = classname;
        classToLoad = Class.forName(classname, true, child);
        instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
    }
}
```

So basically, in the end I will have two DynamicLoader objects, called jar1 and jar2. Then I will perform method run() on both jar1 and jar2 objects by

```
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("run");
method.invoke(instance);
```

The problem I have is that, when I run my MainApplication with EclipseIDE, with a.jar and b.jar in lib folder, the result is correct. In console, lines "a.jar" and "b.jar" are printed out. But when I export MainApplication to a runnable jar and run with command line, in the console, two lines "a.jar" and "a.jar" are printed, although it worked fine when running during eclipse. 

Can somebody show me what did I do wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you running it from the command line? (you do *not* want to put a.jar and b.jar on the classpath, because then Java will look for classes in them first, before it looks in your child classloader)

Comment: I run with this command, "java -jar mainApplication.jar "

Comment: the a.jar and b.jar are not included in the classpath of mainApplication, the application will look into the lib folder and load all files with .jar extension at the end